# Unnamed namespace and Local variables in source files

Tags: c++, namespaces

I always use unnamed namespace inside source files in place of static but I've come across some code that just defines it in the source file.

```
// Source file foo.cpp

const float someFloat = 3.2f;

Foo::Foo() {
  std::cout << someFloat << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any disadvantage do doing this over unnamed namespace?

Comment: Defines *what*? A normal global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case some other `.cpp` file could use `extern const float someFloat;` to pull that variable in, which is not possible if the variable is static or in an unnamed namespace.

One could argue that the possibility to use `extern` is a disadvantage as it might break encapsulation in certain situations.